# Chart is not displayed by using parameter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am a newbe and I am trying to build a parameter for smallmultiples.

This is my data set
[image]

I am trying to build Small Multiples for every supply type (Versorgungsart). The idea is to use the columns 'Establishments,' 'remuneration,' 'hours worked,' and 'persons employed' (Betriebe, Entgelte, geleistete Arbeitsstunden und tätige Personen) as filters. For this, I've created a parameter. I would like to switch between 'Establishments,' 'remuneration,' hours worked,' and 'persons employed' for each supply type.

The result should looks like this
[image]

But It doesn't work. The problem is (what I assume) I couldn't link the parameter to the viz. And this is the result.

[image]

Does anybody have any idea how can I fix it? I would really appriacet your help!

Here ismy workbook: https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/reports/d10e1a46-8720-4200-ab3c-e3540a0af811?experience=power-bi

Thank you!